# How do you use an Oauth callback between React and Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to integrate MailChimp's API into my React App which will allow users to authorize their MailChimp accounts for use in my app. I haven't found a tutorial on it, so I'm following this tutorial which uses only express: https://www.codementor.io/mattgoldspink/integrate-mailchimp-with-nodejs-app-du10854xp

I've gone through Mailchimp to set up my app/my client secret/client id, etc:

#### Redirect URI

```http://127.0.0.1:3001/mailchimp/auth/callback````

I kept the same express code as the tutorial, except I put my client secret in a .env file:

## server.js

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const mailchimpClientId = `${process.env.MC_CLIENT}`

app.get('/mailchimp/auth/authorize', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      'response_type': 'code',
      'client_id': mailchimpClientId,
      'redirect_uri': 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/mailchimp/auth/callback'
    }));
});
```

However, in the tutorial, the callback function is in an HTML file written like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Integrate MailChimp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/mailchimp/auth/authorize">Connect with MailChimp</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've added this (using JSX syntax):

## MailChimp.jsx

```
class MailChimp extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>MailChimp Auth</h1>
        <a href={'http://127.0.0.1:3000/mailchimp/auth/authorize'}>Mailchimp</a>
      </div >
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(MailChimp);
```

On clicking that link inside my React App's route `localhost:3001/mailchimp`, I'm sent to mailchimp where I sucessfully login with my account (not the one requesting permission) and I am returned to the react app.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
GET /mailchimp/auth/callback 404 2.818 ms - 162
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I've scoured the web trying to find a working example of using React & Express for MailChimp Oauth for app authorization but I haven't found one. My question is, did I set something up wrong in the redirect, or is there a better recommendation for handling this request in React?

Comment: Does it make a difference to use `localhost` in place of `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: @GBWDev Yes, the documentation requires that you use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Can i have a look to your repo? I need to implement same, Thanks

Comment: @KaleemElahi I have an example here using GITHUB for OAuth access: https://github.com/seanbfield/pern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 error is saying that you don't have a route that maps to `/mailchimp/auth/callback`. Looks like from your code you haven't written that.

Unless you haven't provided the code for it, you need the route handler mentioned with the code in the tutorial:

```
app.get('/mailchimp/auth/callback', function(req, res) {
  request.post('https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token')
         .send(querystring.stringify({
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, my eyes glazed over and thought it was the same as ```mailchimp/auth/authorize```. I'm able to login and a callback code.